# LOW Read Write Speed when Land, Transform data in Amazon Redhisft using Talend Open Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift, talend

My problem is simple. 
I have following flow of data:
**Amazon RDS MYSQL Database -> Talend Open Studio in EC2 Machine -> Amazon Redshift**

Now the problem is that when Irun a Select INSERT statement, it loads data really fast. But when I use *tRedshiftinput* or *tRedshiftoutput* it gets really slow ( I think it loads row by row and not in Bulk).

I have heard about the technique of converting the data into S3 file and then copying that file into Red-shift and I don't want to use that technique as this a Batch based project which runs periodically and we cant afford any file read/write complexities.

Please Help me to identify the problem in this flow or technique. 
Thank you.

Comment: Try disabling the *tRedshiftoutput* to see if there is any difference in speed. Do this for every component to find the culprit. Alternatively, set the *Use cursor* advanced option [from here](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tRedshiftInput).

Comment: In the advanced settigns make sure that you enable: for inputs Use cursor for outputs use batch.

Comment: @tobi6 By desabling tRedshiftoutput the job will only read data but would not be able to write it. As we have 2 components for LANDING job i,e tRedshiftinput (geting data from MYSQL src) and tRedshiftoutput (to load in target)

Comment: @BalazsGunics, I changed the settings but still it has low read and write speed i,e ~50 row per sec.

Comment: You are not supposed to run the job without the output in your environment permanently. As stated, it is just *to see if there is any difference in speed*. Then it has to be activated again. This is an approach to find out *if the speed getting the data is low or the speed putting the data in the database or in between*.